# Error response from daemon: getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-registry

When I try to pull an image from a private Docker Registry I get the error

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://XX.XX.XX.XXX:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp XX.XX.XX.XXX:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

The docker registry is definitely listening on the correct port. Running

```
ss --listen --tcp -n -p
```

Gives the result

```
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                           Local Address:Port                                             Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      128                                                          *:22                                                          *:*
LISTEN      0      128                                                         :::22                                                         :::*
LISTEN      0      128                                                         :::5000                                                       :::*
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to solve this problem? I'm really stumped by it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, seems like it related to certificates on your registry host.
Check here on how to fix that: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23620

Comment: Thanks for this. This has sorted it!