# Errors with notification endpoint for local docker registry

Tags: java, spring, rest, docker-registry, docker-java

I have successfully deployed a local docker registry and implemented an listener endpoint to receive event notifications following the documentation [for configuration](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/) using a sample  [insecure configuration file](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/cmd/registry/config-example.yml). Pushing, pulling and listing images work well. However, i still receive no event notification.  The registry logs are throwing some errors i do not really understand:

```
level=error msg="retryingsink: error writing events: httpSink{http://localhost:5050/event}: error posting: Post http://localhost:5050/event: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5050: getsockopt: connection refused, retrying"
```

I will appreciate any info.

The endpoint listener is implemented in java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/event",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
public void listener(@RequestBody Events event) {

Event[] e = event.getEvents();
Event ee = new Event();

for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(e.length);
    System.out.println(e[i].toString());

}
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789456/error-response-from-daemon-getsockopt-connection-refused

Comment: @YohannesGebremariam the referred answer is different to my issue. I can list,pull and push images. Also I have not configured certificates since this is  optional. I might have an issue with writing registry events to the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So  after several hours of research i.e. inspecting the private registry logs, i realized the media-type of the messages posted by registry listener to notification endpoints is either `application/octet stream` or `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json`. Hence my solution was to permit all media types using the annotation `consumes =  "*/*"` as specified in this [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) i.e.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/event",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes =  "*/*")
```